# Segmentation fault when listing the words in a sentence

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

```
int getter2(char str[])
{
    int len=0;
    scanf("%100[^\n]s",str);
    while (str[len++] != '\0');
    return len-1;
}

int wordmaker(char str[],char word[15][15],int len)
{
    int i,temp=0,j=0;
    for (i=0;i<len;i++){
        if (((str[i]>='a') && (str[i]<='z')) || ((str[i]>='A') && (str[i]<='Z'))){
            word[j][temp++] = str[i];
        }
        else{
            j++;
            temp=0;
        }   
    }
    for (i=0;i<15;i++)
        for (j=0;j<15;j++)
            printf("%c",word[i][j]);

}

int main()
{
    char line[max],word[15][15];
    int len;
    printf("%d\n%s\n",getter2(line),line);
    wordmaker(line,word,len);

}
```

core dumped.segmentation fault.the wordmaker function is faulty.t does'nt end.when i run the program i get the sentence i put properly along with proper length.the wordmaker function seems to be the problem.
can someone help me debug it.

Comment: `len` is not initialized in main.

Comment: Contrary to popular belief, `scanf()`'s `%[]` conversion is not a modifier to `%s`, it's its own thing. So drop that `s` after the closing square bracket. Also use `strlen()`, not a loop.

Comment: `printf("%d\n%s\n",getter2(line),line);` looks like UB to me: A function call is a sequence point, but the order in which the arguments are evaluated is unspecified, `line` (last argument) could be evaluated before `getter2` is called. cf [Sequence points in C #4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point). because `line` decays into a pointer, it doesn't matter here, but it's a risky way to write code.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed some of the problems in the code and got it working. There's problem a though: If you do not input 15 words, it will print garbage (because of the `for (i = 0; i < 15; i++)` loop in `wordmaker`).

General points:

1. You do not need the `s` in your format string for `scanf()`.
2. Return type of `wordmaker` should be `void`.
3. Added zero terminating byte to each string.
4. Printing strings instead of individual characters.
5. Assigned the return value of `getter2` to `len` inside `main`.

All that is in the code:

```
/* str.c
 * gcc -o str str.c -Wall
 */
#include <stdio.h>

/* As pointed by @BLUEPIXY, this should be 101 because of the format 
 * string of scanf. It will read 100 characters from stdin into the
 * string, but it doesn't take into account the terminating NULL byte.
 */
#define max     101

int getter2(char str[])
{
    int len = 0;

    /* no need the trailing s in format string */
    scanf("%100[^\n]", str);

    while (str[len++] != '\0');
    return len - 1;
}

/* changed return type to void, since you're not returning anything */
void wordmaker(char str[], char word[15][15], int len)
{
    int i, temp = 0, j = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (((str[i] >= 'a') && (str[i] <= 'z'))
            || ((str[i] >= 'A') && (str[i] <= 'Z'))) {
            word[j][temp++] = str[i];
        } else {
            /* put the terminating null byte on each string */
            word[j][temp] = 0x0;

            j++;
            temp = 0;
        }
    }
    /* print the strings, not their characters
     *
     * If you use a loop to print characters, you need to have 15 byte
     * strings, otherwise you're gonna print garbage.
     */
    for (i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        printf("%s\n", word[i]);

}

int main()
{
    char line[max], word[15][15];
    int len;

    /* here a little modification to initialize the variable 'len' */
    printf("%d\n%s\n", (len = getter2(line)), line);
    wordmaker(line, word, len);

}
```

As a side note, if you include `ctype.h`, you can change `((str[i] >= 'a') && (str[i] <= 'z')) || ((str[i] >= 'A') && (str[i] <= 'Z'))` for `isalpha(str[i])`, which is clearer. The [isalpha() manual](https://linux.die.net/man/3/isalpha).